# Android inflated layout alignment

Tags: android

I have a RelativeLayout that I am aligning to the right. If i display the layout with setContentView everything works fine but if I try to display the inflated view, it's not aligned to the right anymore. Does anyone know if this could be fixed?

Thanks.

EDIT:

The XML is very simple, i only have a RelativeLayout with some padding. I am using `android:layout_gravity="top|right"`.

If I display the whole layout with setContentView(), the RelativeLayout is properly aligned, but when I try the following code the alignment breaks:

```
inflater = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);
View inflated = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout, null);
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout);
layout.addView(inflated);
```

I am doing this because I want to be able to add the `inflated` view multiple times.

Comment: What do you mean by "if I try to display the inflated view"? Please post your XML

Comment: Please post entire XML, and what do you mean by alignment breaks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to see without the XML but generally when you call `inflate` you should pass a root view otherwise any layout parameters you specify in your XML layout will be lost.

Try this, maybe?

```
inflater = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout);
View inflated = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout, layout, false);
layout.addView(inflated);
```